# Is there a way to stop Eclipse from collapsing all folders every time it is opened?

Tags: java, eclipse

Every time I open Eclipse, all the folders in the package explorer are collapsed, and I have to re-open them every time. Is there a way to maintain the file structure every time Eclipse is closed and re-opened?

Comment: It saves my last position for me.

Comment: It used to be like that for me too, but idk why it stopped.

Comment: Under the ' Package Ex...' tab there is a button with back and fourth arrows '<-- -->', but with the arrows above and below each other.  It it is depressed Eclipse will open the package when you click in an open file.  I am not sure if this will help you but its all I have.  Mine also saved the last position.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you @cliff2310